# Command not found for Vowpal Wabbit Utilties

Tags: vowpalwabbit

**Summary**

I installed Vowpal Wabbit on my Mac using the GitHub site [here](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit) (and also with Homebrew when I started troubleshooting).  Both installs worked, as in I was able to use the `vw` command and get the reply "For more information use: vw --help".

**Problem**

However, the utilities under 'vowpal_wabbit/utl' don't seem to work for me (e.g. `-bash: vw-top-errors: command not found`, `-bash: vw-varinfo: command not found`).  I tried to solve by making an alias (`alias vw=/Users/williamliu/GitHub/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/vw`), but that didn't seem to resolve the issue.  I also tried to point my PATH to vowpalwabbit's utilities (export `PATH=/Users/williamliu/GitHub/vowpal_wabbit/vowpalwabbit/vw:$PATH`)

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your `PATH=...` setting doesn't work is you used a file-name (rather than a directory path) there.

In your particular case, the correct setting is:

`export PATH=/Users/williamliu/GitHub/vowpal_wabbit/utl:$PATH`

(Please make sure that this is indeed the directory where the utilities reside.)

Comment: Thanks!  I did your Path export and then made the alias for my commands I needed in the .bash_profile like this: `alias vw-top-errors="/Users/williamliu/GitHub/vowpal_wabbit/utl/vw-top-errors"`

Comment: Glad it helped.  Note that you don't need the alias setting if your PATH is set correctly.  That's exactly what `PATH` is for: to find the command where it is installed so you don't have to type the full path in each invocation.  Also: aliases won't work across processes and will force you to define an additional alias for every individual command. You should place the `PATH` setting in your `~/.bashrc` which runs at the start of every new bash process.

Comment: Oh you're right, I took out the alias' in my `~/.bash_profile` and it worked just fine.  Thanks again @arielf